# I can't get my radio button checked to see the result of calculation android(using onclicklistener)

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I am creating a simple calculator and I use radio buttons for choosing operators, but I faced the problem with radio button check. I hope somebody will help me. Thanks in advance.

Here are the following codes:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tekstas"
        android:id="@+id/textas"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/nr1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/nr2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/nr3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/nr4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/veiksmai">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/plius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pliusas"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/minusas"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/daugyba"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/daugyba"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rezultatas"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RadioGroup rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.veiksmai);
        EditText n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr1);
        EditText n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr2);
        EditText n3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr3);
        EditText n4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr4);
        EditText edtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        int selected = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton plus2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
        RadioButton minus2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
        RadioButton multi = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);

        if("+".equals(plus2.getText())) {
            float result = Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString())+ Float.parseFloat(n3.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(n4.getText().toString());
            edtResult.setText(Float.toString(result));
        }else if("-".equals(minus2.getText())){
            float result = Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString())- Float.parseFloat(n3.getText().toString())- Float.parseFloat(n4.getText().toString());
            edtResult.setText(Float.toString(result));
        }else if("*".equals(multi.getText())){
            float result = Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString())* Float.parseFloat(n3.getText().toString())* Float.parseFloat(n4.getText().toString());
            edtResult.setText(Float.toString(result));
                }
    }

};

        // Getting reference of the button btnResult
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id. btn);

        // Setting onclick listener
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

}

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to id your elements in onCreate:

```
    RadioGroup rg =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.veiksmai);
    EditText n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr1);
    EditText n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr2);
    EditText n3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr3);
    EditText n4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr4);
    EditText edtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    RadioButton plus2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plius);
    RadioButton minus2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    RadioButton multi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.daugyba);
```

And the attach an onCheckedChangedListener to it, not an onClick listener:

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
            if (arg0.getChildAt(0).isPressed()
                    || arg0.getChildAt(1).isPressed()
                    || arg0.getChildAt(2).isPressed()) {

                if (arg0.getChildAt(0).isPressed()) {
                    //do your stuff here
                } else if (arg0.getChildAt(1).isPressed()) {
                    //do your stuff here
                } else if (arg0.getChildAt(2).isPressed()) {
                    //do your stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have done that, but i can't now insert the button that show result, because it was set onclicklistener. outside public void class.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have

```
android:inputType="number"
```

this does not allow decimals or negatives. if you want decimals use

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

if you want to allow decimals and negative numbers use

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

When you use:

```
android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
```

All you need to do is make a method passing in a view and do whatever it is you want on button (or radioButton) click. I made each radio button have their own method named onRadioButtonClicked  for plus, onRadioButtonClicked1 for minus , and onRadioButtonClicked2 for multiplication. Then used the changed sign to get results in an onClickListener for a button.

```
private char sign;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.veiksmai);
    final EditText n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr1);
    final EditText n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr2);
    final EditText n3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr3);
    final EditText n4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr4);
    final EditText edtResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    RadioButton plus2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.plius);
    RadioButton minus2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    RadioButton multi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.daugyba);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sign == '+') {
                float result = Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(n3.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(n4.getText().toString());
                edtResult.setText(Float.toString(result));
            } else if (sign == '-') {
                float result = Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(n3.getText().toString()) - Float.parseFloat(n4.getText().toString());
                edtResult.setText(Float.toString(result));
            } else if (sign == '*') {
                float result = Float.parseFloat(n1.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(n2.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(n3.getText().toString()) * Float.parseFloat(n4.getText().toString());
                edtResult.setText(Float.toString(result));
            }
        }
    });
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    sign = '+';
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked1(View view) {
    sign = '-';
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked2(View view) {
    sign = '*';
}
```